# Calling a webservice only once using tasks

Tags: c#

I'm in the process of learning async/await operators. I am trying to figure out how to solve the following problem:

I have a method `Foo()` that sets a property. It does this with data from a network call. The `Foo()` method could be called by multiple callers at the same time. The network call is slow, so I am caching the result so that multiple calls will just get the cached data.

```
    public async Task Foo()
    {
        string key = "some unique cache key";

        if (_cacheService.Get(cacheKey, out int someNumber))
        {
            MyProperty = someNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            number = await _externalCallService.GetACoolNumber();
            _cacheService.Set(amount, cacheKey, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1));
            MyProperty = number;
        }
    }
```

However, I'm running into the problem of multiple calls potentially calling the service and caching the result at the same time. I tried putting the call to the external server in a lock codeblock, but that results in an error, as using the await keyword in a lock is now allowed. I have tried googling, but am not really sure what the correct term for this problem is.

How do I make sure only 1 running task calls `_externalCallService.GetACoolNumber()`, and the other tasks get a cached result?

Comment: Go to msdn to get documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: This can be useful: https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SemaphoreSlim`

```
Class Test
{
     private readonly IMyService _myService;
     private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _defaultsMutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
     public Test(IMyService myService)
     {
          _myService = myService;
     }


     public async Task FireMutexMethod()
     {

          await _defaultsMutex.WaitAsync();
          try 
          {
              //do some work
          }
          finally
          {
                _defaultsMutex.Release();
          }

     }
}
```

If you are in the caching phase. you need to await your method with SemaphoreSlim so that other threads cannot get in

Comment: Worked great for my use case, thanks. I'm slightly disappointed that MS hasn't provided some easy to use keyword like `lock` for this problem, as I can't imagine being the only one that has encountered it.

Comment: lock is intentionally not implemented by MS team in order to prevent developer errors. because using lock statement in async method causes Deadlocks.